# Using gorilla/websocket with the MATLAB Engine

Tags: matlab, go, websocket, ffi, gorilla

I am trying to make a simple Go Websocket server that will allow clients to talk to MATLAB. I managed to use the MATLAB Engine from Go properly, as in I am able to send commands to MATLAB and receive the answers back, but for some reason getting the command from a Websocket client and sending it to MATLAB fails.

The server receives the message properly, but the message is not passed to MATLAB (or I cannot get the output properly)...

I have included the relevant Go code and console output below, and the more details can be found on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jebej/647503c638e7ce7e68b68552fec15806).

**Go server:**

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // Start a MATLAB session
    s := gm.OpenMSession()
    defer gm.CloseMSession(s)
    // Check if MATLAB is up
    fmt.Println("MATLAB v" + gm.EvalString(s, "version"))
    // Tell user what to do
    tell := "MATLAB was loaded, please enter your commands:"
    fmt.Println(tell)
    if err = conn.WriteMessage(ws.TextMessage, []byte(tell)); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Main REPL loop
    for {
        fmt.Println("Waiting for incoming message...")
        _, p, errin := conn.ReadMessage()
        if errin != nil {
            fmt.Println("Close message received!")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Whooo, here it is: " + string(p))

        // Feed message to MATLAB
        res := gm.EvalString(s, string(p))

        // Send response to client
        fmt.Println("Sending response: " + res)
        if err := conn.WriteMessage(ws.TextMessage, []byte(res)); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Client disconnected!")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Done! Now we can start again!")
    }
    fmt.Println("Closing down the conn")
    conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("Closing down the sesh")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":30000", nil)
}
```

**Output:**

```
MATLAB v
ans =

9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)


MATLAB was loaded, please enter your commands:
Waiting for incoming message...
Whooo, here it is: 2+2
Sending response: 
ans =

9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)


Done! Now we can start again!
Waiting for incoming message...
```

Comment: Cross posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Jc1a2U4DwVM

Comment: You say that you can send commands and receive answers back without using websockets.  Take the code and run it in a goroutine and see if ti works.  Perhaps the matlib requires that all code run on the main thread or something.

Comment: I just tried and starting the engine in a goroutine works properly.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. Show the code that works without websockets.

Comment: Me neither, it's driving me crazy! I included on the gist (which I realize I had not linked) an example without the websocket, which is also the one I tried directly in a goroutine.

Comment: Evaluate the exact same expressions in the two apps and see if that makes a difference..  The websocket app evals "version", the other app does not. The websocket app prints the version output twice. Perhaps there's a bug in matlab with the "version" expression.

Comment: That didn't work either, when I do that, the function seems to read an empty buffer and outputs nothing, instead of that version string. Thanks for all the help by the way, I know this is hard to troubleshoot without being able to do it yourself...

Comment: Please be more specific about where the empty buffer is read and where the nothing output is returned. Is the empty buffer from the websocket or is it the return from the library?

Comment: I read the result of evaluating expressions from a buffer: https://gist.github.com/jebej/647503c638e7ce7e68b68552fec15806#file-engine-go-L38